# ¿Utilizar Windows.h es mala práctica?

Tags: c++, windows

### **Hola a todos!**

Me preguntaba, solo por mera curiosidad, si utilizar bibliotecas como **Windows.h** u otras de otros **SO**, es considerado mala práctica. Yo soy mucho de utilizarlas, obviamente si es realmente necesario, y se me pasó por la cabeza esta idea.

**Espero a sus Respuestas...**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `Windows.h` no es estándar.

> Me preguntaba, solo por mera curiosidad, si utilizar bibliotecas como **Windows.h** u otras de otros **SO**, es considerado mala práctica.

El problema reside en que no son estándar. Cualquier librería no estándar es por definición no [portable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidad), más aún cuando se trata de una librería exclusiva de un sistema operativo.

#### ¿Tan malo es no ser portable?

Si la portabilidad no es un requerimiento de tu programa, no debería ser problemático usar cabeceras dependientes de plataforma.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Paula! 
No lo había visto de ese modo... En todo caso,, si voy a realizar un programa portable, detectaré el SO y trabajaré con su biblioteca (si es necesarío). :D